# cakephp211 date insertion

Tags: cakephp-2.1

this is my variable:

```
     <?php 
     //...
     $creat='2000-03-15'  ,from an input field.
     ?>
```

this is my insertion code:

```
     <?php 
     //...
       $this->Comment->updateAll(         
              array('Comment.c' => $creat ),
              array('Comment.id' => '3'  ));
     ?>
```

when i want to save it in a table which have a date field type, instead of '2000-03-15', i have '0000-00-00'?
why?
thanks for comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the updateAll function does not escape your input. It will also not wrap your data in quotes.

In your example, to properly escape your $creat variable, i would suggest using the following code:

```
<?php
App::uses('Sanitize', 'Utility');
$Comment->updateAll(array(
    'Comment.c' => "'" . Sanitize::escape($creat) . "'"
), array(
    'Comment.id' => 3
));
```

We wrap the date with quotes and also pass it through Sanitize::escape to make sure we protect ourselves against SQL injection.